# Create a membership list with employee name

Tags: profile, smartgroups

I have a public directory list that is created based on a relationship with an organization that is set-up as a smart group.  I have a profile that lists the organizations that are included in the smart group along with their web address and email address.  I also want to include the employees or contacts for each organization.  How do you create a list or directory on a web page that includes an organization name and an individual's first and last name?

I see that this is a limitation of CiviCRM - can't combine individuals with organizations, but that doesn't seem practical.  When you create a directory of member organizations it seems appropriate to include a contact name.  How have others handled this problem?

I am using CiviCRM 4.4 and WordPress.

Comment: From your other question, I assume you're using Civi 4.4 and WordPress? Please confirm with an edit to your question. Thanks!

Comment: Is the directory meant to be 'public' in some way or is the list for staff/admin users only?

Answer (score 1):

To get the employees, run an advanced search.  In the relationships section, select the relationship type and enter the organization that the employers are related to.  Then, go up to the top section and find **Display Results As**.  Select "Related Contacts" and then in the relationship type drop-down that appears, select "Employee Of".

You should get results of all the employees.  Create a smart group from this search, and have your directory profile use this new group instead.

Finally, to display the employees' employers, add the field "Current Employer" (available under "Individual") to the profile, making it visible as a result column ("In selector").  (You may need to remove any organization-specific fields and/or create a fresh profile as your profile is now a listing of individuals rather than organizations.)

Answer (score 0):

Two ways I can think of for identifying the lead contact for an organisation- a contact reference custom field, or a relationship. I'd generally prefer the relationship (you can keep historical information, have more than one of them, etc) but the custom field would be easier to show in a profile.

Comment: I am using relationship.  I have a household name called Affiliates.  Organizations that are Affiliates are "Relationship as" Affiliate.